# C# XNA Add a GameComponent from within a GameComponent

Tags: c#, xna, drawablegamecomponent

```
public class Menu : DrawableGameComponent
{
    ContentManager Content;
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    Audio MenuMusic;

    public Menu(Game game) : base(game)
    {
        spriteBatch = Game.Services.GetService(typeof(SpriteBatch)) as SpriteBatch;
        graphics = Game.Services.GetService(typeof(GraphicsDeviceManager)) as GraphicsDeviceManager;

        Content = game.Content;
        Content.RootDirectory = @"Content\Menu\";

        *MenuMusic =  new Audio(game);* // Instantiate the new DrawableGameComponent

        Game.Components.Add(this);

        MenuMusic.PauseTune = false;
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        Menustate = MenuState.LoadContent;
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
         base.LoadContent();
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        base.UnloadContent();
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}

public class Audio : DrawableGameComponent
{

    public bool PauseTune
    {
        get { return PauseTune; }
        set { PauseTune = value; }
    }

    SoundEffect Tune = null;
    SoundEffectInstance SFXInstance;

    public Audio(Game game) : base(game)
    {
        *game.Components.Add(this)*;// This is the problem. It adds an entirely new Game object. :(
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        PauseTune = true;

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        switch (Game1.Gamestate)
        {
            case GameState.Menu:
                string AudioPath = @"Audio\";
                Tune = Game.Content.Load<SoundEffect>(AudioPath + "Tune");
                break;
            case GameState.InitialiseGame:
                break;
            case GameState.PlayGame:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (Tune != null) SFXInstance = Tune.CreateInstance();

        base.LoadContent();
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        base.UnloadContent();
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (Tune != null)
        {
            if (PauseTune)
            {
                if (SFXInstance.State == SoundState.Playing)
                    SFXInstance.Pause();
            }
            else
            {
                if (SFXInstance.State != SoundState.Playing)
                    SFXInstance.Play();
            }
        }
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

The probelem comes when I use the Menu to add a new Audio class instance.
The Audio constructor attempts to add the new GameCompent but fails.
What it actually does is create an entirely new Game instance, which then goes on to instantiate a new Menu that attempts to add a new Audio class instance..... Until I eventually get a - would you beleive? - stackoverflow error.

What am I doing wrong? / How can I add one component from within another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOH! Some days I should never turn on my computer :)

Or better yet - after a long, tiring day do NOT mess with mycode.

A self-referencing PauseTune property.

Comment: Don't forget you can mark your own answers as _the answer_. That way you get _brownie-points_ :)